# How to differentiate between user swipe and tap action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing a app in which I have a view which contains subView in it. 
I want to track both swipe and tap actions such as a single click.

Actions should be tracked only when the user touches within my subview. When the user taps I want to perform one action, when the user swipes I want perform another.

For tracking the swipe, I implemented `UIGestureRecognizer` and it is working fine. But I don't know how to track the tap option. Please guide me how to achieve this.

The main thing is, when I tap it should call tap action only and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**UITapGestureRecognizer**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for tap gestures.

> "UITapGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer
>   that looks for single or multiple taps. For the gesture to be
>   recognized, the specified number of fingers must tap the view a
>   specified number of times."

This method includes the `numberOfTapsRequired` ("The number of taps for the gesture to be recognized.") and `numberOfTouchesRequired` ("The number of fingers required to tap for the gesture to be recognized") properties where you can set exactly how you want it to react to user action.

In this case, as you only want it to be activated when tapped once, the default settings for both these properties (both have default values of 1) should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get the information is **Defining How Gesture Recognizers Interact** of [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW9)

> When a view has multiple gesture recognizers attached to it, you may
>   want to alter how the competing gesture recognizers receive and
>   analyze touch events. By default, there is no set order for which
>   gesture recognizers receive a touch first, and for this reason touches
>   can be passed to gesture recognizers in a different order each time.
>   You can override this default behavior to:
>
> - Specify that one gesture recognizer should analyze a touch before another gesture recognizer.
> - Allow two gesture recognizers to operate simultaneously.
> - Prevent a gesture recognizer from analyzing a touch.