# TableView Cell button click and swipe gesture mix issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have implemented `tableview` with swipe for delete and flag purpose.
But when i swipe right to left then other button(apart from swipe) click called randomly.

Please help me .

These are the following code.

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Button 1" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    {

    }];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //arbitrary color
    UITableViewRowAction *button2 = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Button 2" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {

                                    }];
    button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //arbitrary color

    return @[button, button2]; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: show the screenshot it will help to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896802/how-to-differentiate-between-user-swipe-and-tap-action refer this link

Answer (score 0):

add gesture delegate in your code and check class of gesture recognizer

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer )gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch )touch
```

Comment: I added following code but i am still getting same issue.

Comment: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(nonnull UITouch *)touch{
    
    return NO; 
}

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleViewLeft)];
    swipeGestureLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGestureLeft.delegate=self;
    swipeGestureLeft.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
    
    
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];
    

    
}