# Objective-C: TableView Delete with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my TableView, I allow users to delete their posts using the swipe to delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

However, I also allow users to tap the cell to open up a detail view of the post:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // segue and stuff
}
```

The problem is, when the user swipes to delete, it also triggers the didSelect method and opens up the detail view. How can I make sure didSelectRowAtIndexPath only triggers on taps, while the delete triggers on a drag swipe?

Comment: Have you che checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896802/how-to-differentiate-between-user-swipe-and-tap-action ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a UITableViewController + UIStoryboard and connect your detail view segue to push in your cell prototype selection outlet, this works as expected (didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called when swiping):

```
@interface TableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cellTitles;
@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.cellTitles = [@[@"Apple", @"Banana", @"Carrot", @"Millenium Falcon"] mutableCopy];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return self.cellTitles.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.textLabel.text = self.cellTitles[indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.cellTitles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have add the following delegate method as well:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return YES - we will be able to delete all rows
    return YES;
}
```

The whole implementation would be

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return YES - we will be able to delete all rows
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Based on your updated question, then I would add a edit button on the right top side of the tableview to inform user to delete the selected cell. Check the following threads

- [change Table to Edit mode and delete Rows inside a normal ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148229/change-table-to-edit-mode-and-delete-rows-inside-a-normal-viewcontroller)
- [iOS delete a tableview row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961581/ios-delete-a-tableview-row)

Here is also good tutorial, it is worth to check

- http://www.appcoda.com/model-view-controller-delete-table-row-from-uitableview/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do have the canEditRowAtIndexPath method included in my code as well. Please see the edit above.

Comment: I'm not having trouble deleting the row. I'm having trouble with didSelectRowAtIndexPath triggering when I'm trying to swipe to show the delete button.